# Ignorar primera página para contar número de páginas en mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Estoy creando un PDF con [mPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) (versión 6.1) pero no sé si hay una manera de que comience a contar desde la segunda página, es decir, ignore la primera página y desde la segunda cuente 1, 2, 3, etc. ¿Cómo podría hacerse eso?

He intentado algo como esto, que sí me cuenta las páginas, pero me sigue contando la primera hoja. Estoy llamando los estilos directamente en el html, es decir:

```
<htmlpagefooter name="Chapter2FooterOdd" style="display:none">
    <div style="text-align: right;">Página {PAGENO} de {nbpg}</div>
</htmlpagefooter>

<htmlpagefooter name="Chapter2FooterEven" style="display:none">
    <div style="text-align: right;">Página {PAGENO} de {nbpg}</div>
</htmlpagefooter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco la documentacion de la libreria me encontre este ejemplo espero te sirva

```
<?php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

// Double-side document - mirror margins
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = 1;

// Set a simple Footer including the page number
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');

// Turn off (suppress) page numbering from the start of the document
$mpdf->AddPage('','','','','on');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Front Cover Pages');

// You could also do this using
// $mpdf->AddPage('','NEXT-ODD','1','i','off');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Foreword and Introduction');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak type="NEXT-ODD" pagenumstyle="1" />');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Your Book text');

$mpdf->Output();
```

[aquí tienes mas información](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html)

Comment: Hola!, gracias por responder, ya había intentado eso, si bien, sí me cuenta las páginas, pero me sigue contanto la primera hoja, y pues  estoy llamando los estilos directamente en el html, es decir:
`<htmlpagefooter name="Chapter2FooterOdd" style="display:none">
        <div style="text-align: right;">Página {PAGENO} de {nbpg}</div>
    </htmlpagefooter>

    <htmlpagefooter name="Chapter2FooterEven" style="display:none">
        <div style="text-align: right;">Página {PAGENO} de {nbpg}</div>
    </htmlpagefooter>`

Comment: Hola @tiyeli, aunque esto puede servir para solucionar el problema, sería ideal que añadieras una breve explicación de qué es lo que hace o cómo resuelve el problema. No todos los usuarios saben inglés y pueden no entender el código sin más.

Comment: @RafaelGaitan ese comentario debería ir en la pregunta en sí también. Es importante que los usuarios sepan lo que has intentado y los problemas/dificultades con las que te estás encontrando.

Comment: en el metodo $mpdf->AddPage('','','','','on');
intentaste cambiar on por off?
deberia quedar de esta manera 
$mpdf->AddPage('','','','','off');